# ElException method not found

Tags: java-ee-5

I work in a project using seam and jsf.  I want to call a method from view part (an xhtml file) .

I have this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{thePoliciesAdmin.getMinusUsage()}"/>
```

I have the method created in thePoliciesAdmin class but when I run the app I get the following exception:

> javaxElException ..Method not found :  thePoliciesAdmin.getMinusUsage().

What can I do?